# Classification of values according to criteria, Any solution?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get a ranking like this rank ?? in this case there are repeated criteria and names, each name has to have its exclusive classification without interfering with the others under different names, any solution? The classification has to be according to the value corresponding to the name, from highest to lowest[image]